# Implementation of Shortest Path Graph in Python Class

Tags: python, class, undirected-graph

> Hi! I am new to Python and I am struggling for many hours so far with some problem regarding Shortest Path Algorithm implementation in Python.
>
> I am expected to solve some task about finding shortest paths (graph problem) among given persons, and at the end find a common person who connects all of them.

I've made something like this so far:

```
import itertools
    
class centralperson():

def initialization(self,N,data,a,b,c):
    self.data = data
    self.N = N
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    self.list_of_values = [self.a,self.b,self.c]
    self.list_of_paths = []
    self.common_person = []

def makeGraph(self):
    
    # Create dict with empty list for each key
    graph = {key: [] for key in range(self.N)}
    self.graph = graph

    for key in self.graph:
        for x in self.data:
            if key in x:
                
                x = x.copy()
                x.remove(key)
                self.graph[key].extend(x)

def find_path(self,start, end):
    path = []
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if start not in self.graph.keys():
        raise ValueError('No such key in graph!')
    for node in self.graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = self.find_path(self.graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return self.list_of_paths.append(path)


def findPaths(self):
    
    for pair in itertools.combinations(self.list_of_values, r=5):
        self.find_path(*pair)


def commonperson(self):
    
    list_of_lens = {}
    commonalities = set(self.list_of_paths[0]) & set(self.list_of_paths[1]) & set(self.list_of_paths[2])
    for i in self.list_of_values:
        list_of_lens[i] = (len(self.graph[i]))
    
    if len(commonalities)>1 or len(commonalities)<1:
        for k,v in list_of_lens.items():
            if v==1 and self.graph[k][0] in commonalities:
                output = self.graph[k]
                self.common_person.append(output)
    else:
        output = list(commonalities)
        self.common_person.append(output)
    return 

def printo(self):

    #return(self.common_person[0])
    return(self.list_of_paths,self.list_of_values)
```

> Description of each function and inputs:
>
> N -> number of unique nodes
>
> a,b,c -> some arbitrarily chosen nodes to find common one among them
>
> initialization -> just initialize our global variables used in other methods, and store the list of outputs
>
> makeGraph -> makes an Adjacency List out of an input.
>
> find_path -> find path between two given nodes (backtracking recursion)
>
> findPaths -> it was expected to call find_path here for every combination of A,B,C i.e A->B, A->C, B->C
>
> commonperson -> expected to find common person from the output of list_of_paths list
>
> printo -> print this common person

Generally It works (I'think) when I'am running each function separately. But, when I try to make a huge class of it, it doesn't work :(

I think the problem is with this recursive function `find_path`. It is supposed to find a path between two person given, and append the result path to the list with all paths. Yet, as I have 3 different persons, and `find_path` is a recursive function with only 2 parameters.

Hence, I need to find all paths that connects them (3 paths) and append it to a bigger list `list_of_paths`. I've created a `def findPaths` to make use of `itertools.combinations` and in for loop cal function `find_path` for every combination of start and end argument of this function, but it seems not to work...

Can you help me with this? Also I don't know how to run all the `def functions` at once, because honestly I wouldn't like to run all instances of the class separately... My desired version is to:

> Provide Input to a class i.e : `N,data,a,b,c` where N is number of unique nodes, data is just list of list with networks assigned, and A,B,C are my persons.
>
> Get Output: which is a common person for all this 3 persons, (I planned to store it in `common_person` list.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside you class should be *indented*, i.e.:

```py
class centralperson:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def makeGraph(self, ...):
        ...
```

instead of

```py
class centralperson:
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...

def makeGraph(self, ...):
    ...
```

Try googling for '[python class examples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)'. I hope this helps!

It might also be useful to experiment with simpler classes before working on this problem.

Comment: It is indented originally but as I copied it here I cannot make it so...

Answer (score 0):

```py
itertools.combinations(self.list_of_values, r=5)
```

returns an empty list, since `self.list_of_values` only has 3 elements, from which you cannot pick 5.

Perhaps you meant:

```py
itertools.combinations(self.list_of_values, r=2)
```

Comment: when I set to r=2 it gives an error:
```3 Persona.makeGraph()
--> 4 Persona.findPaths()
      5 Persona.printo()

     43         for pair in itertools.combinations(self.list_of_values, r=2):
--> 44             self.find_path(*pair)


     34         for node in self.graph[start]:
     35             if node not in path:
---> 36                 newpath = self.find_path(self.graph, node, end, path)
     37                 if newpath: return newpath
     38         return self.list_of_paths.append(path)

TypeError: find_path() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given```

Comment: Have a closer look at line 36.